# Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).Pie is not a function -Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, charts

I want to draw **Pie chart** using **Chart.js 2.1.6**

My code :

```
<script src="~/Plugin/Chart.js 2.1.6/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="mychart"></canvas>

var data = [
        {
            value: 300,
            color: "#F7464A",
            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
            label: "Red"
        },
        {
            value: 50,
            color: "#46BFBD",
            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
            label: "Green"
        },
        {
            value: 100,
            color: "#FDB45C",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            label: "Yellow"
        }
    ]
```

`var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
 var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);`

But i get an Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).Pie is not a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have you tried using the following code instead?

```
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Comment: no worries , if it works for you then mark it as correct answer for visibility to other users.